# Populate Form Controls In WPF with Model Object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, object

I would like to know if we can easily populate the form controls with an object which is populated through LINQ.
Following is the code

Code

```
private void REG_NO_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string pattern = "^[A-Z][0-9]*-[0-9]+$";
    regNo = this.REG_NO.Text;

    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Return)
    {
        if (!Regex.Match(regNo, pattern).Success)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Invalid Card Number");
            this.REG_NO.Background = Brushes.OrangeRed;
            this.REG_NO.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            this.REG_NO.Background = (Brush)App.Current.FindResource("InputBoxGradient");

            //Fetch Data From Database
            DataAccessLayer DataLayer = new DataAccessLayer();

            if (!DataLayer.FetchRegisteredCard(regNo, ref RegCard))
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("No Medical Card Found");
            }
            else
            {
                if (RegCard.STATUS == "VALID")
                {
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Card IS Locked Please Contact ADO/Administrator");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The object which is filled and has the same properties name with the same

```
namespace HospitalSystem
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tbl_registration
    {
        public string REG_NO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> R_DATE { get; set; }
        public string EMP_NO { get; set; }
        public string P_NAME { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> P_DOB { get; set; }
        public string RELATION { get; set; }
        public string BLOOD_GROUP { get; set; }
        public string P_MEDICAL_CAT { get; set; }
        public string MARITAL_STATUS { get; set; }
        public string SEX { get; set; }
        public string STATUS { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EXP_DATE { get; set; }
        public string PT_NIC { get; set; }
        public string REMARKS { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> STATUS_DATE { get; set; }
        public string EMP_Dept { get; set; }
        public string EMP_Des { get; set; }
        public string EMP_Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Where 'RegCard' is an object which is populated  at this line I want to populate the Form Controls

```
 if (RegCard.STATUS == "VALID")
 {

 }
```

Please guide me how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for is databinding, which allows you to bind an object to a form and bind that form's controls to the properties of the object. 
Have a look over at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for documentation and examples.